# Beginner JQuery Custom Animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm creating an element which changes states when clicked, however I want it to transition to that state with a specific animation.

I've managed to implement the custom animations but after the animation has finished, it keeps reverting back to the original state.

Here's what I mean: http://codepen.io/FlyingEmu/pen/vEyLd

Any ideas on how to fix this?

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var CardFront = true;
$('.card').click(function () {

  if (CardFront == true) {
    CardFront = false;
    $('#card1').css("animation", "Fly_Out 1s");
    $('#card2').css("animation", "Fly_Out 1s 0.1s");
    $('#card3').css("animation", "Fly_Out 1s 0.2s");
    $('#card4').css("animation", "Fly_Out 1s 0.3s");
  }  
  else {
    CardFront = true;
    $('#card1').css("animation", "Fly_In 1s");
    $('#card2').css("animation", "Fly_In 1s 0.1s");
    $('#card3').css("animation", "Fly_In 1s 0.2s");
    $('#card4').css("animation", "Fly_In 1s 0.3s");
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please post your code. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/t4FUG/

Because after `-prefix-animation`, the CSS styles it applied will revert to its initial state; therefore, you need to manually set its style again. Long story short, add a CSS style rule to `.card` when `CardFront` is `true`.

Add:

```
.card.flyedOut{
    transform: translateX(0%) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}
```

And:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".card").toggleClass("flyedOut");
}, 1000);
```

to the click event.

Comment: Wow tyvm and great explanation as well.